# Task is to parallelize matrix multiplication with p-threads and vectorized with Intel ISPC compiler

Tags: c, parallel-processing, spmd, ispc

In .ispc file using pthread generates errors as follows:
(1) t.ispc:2:13: Error: Illegal to return a "varying" or vector type
from exported function "matrix_mult_pl"
export void * matrix_mult_pl( void *arg )

(2) t.ispc:2:36: Error: Varying pointer type parameter "arg" is
illegal in an exported function.
export void * matrix_mult_pl( void *arg )

(3) t.ispc:6:11: Error: syntax error, unexpected 'int'.
tid = *(int *)(arg); // get the thread ID assigned sequentially.
^^^

and many more errors. Coder is attached below.
Kindly look into the issue of using pthreads in ISPC.

threads.c file

```
/**
 * Thread routine.
 * Each thread works on a portion of the 'matrix1'.
 * The start and end of the portion depend on the 'arg' which
 * is the ID assigned to threads sequentially. 
 */
void * matrix_mult_pl( void *arg )
{
  int rows, cols, j, tid, portion_size, row_start, row_end;

  tid = *(int *)(arg); // get the thread ID assigned sequentially.
  portion_size = size / num_threads;
  row_start = tid * portion_size;
  row_end = (tid+1) * portion_size;

  for (rows = row_start; rows < row_end; ++rows) { // hold row index of 'matrix1'
    for (j = 0; j < size; ++j) { // hold column index of 'matrix2'
     // hold value of a cell
      /* one pass to sum the multiplications of corresponding cells
     in the row vector and column vector. */
      for(cols=0; cols<size; cols++) { 
        result_pl[ rows ][ cols ] += matrix1[ rows ][ j ] * matrix2[ j ][ cols ];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

threads.ispc file

```
export void * matrix_mult_pl( void *arg )
{
  int rows, cols, j, tid, portion_size, row_start, row_end;

  tid = *(int *)(arg); // get the thread ID assigned sequentially.
  portion_size = size / num_threads;
  row_start = tid * portion_size;
  row_end = (tid+1) * portion_size;

  for (rows = row_start; rows < row_end; ++rows) { // hold row index of 'matrix1'
    for (j = 0; j < size; ++j) { // hold column index of 'matrix2'
     // hold value of a cell
      /* one pass to sum the multiplications of corresponding cells
     in the row vector and column vector. */
      for(cols=0; cols<size; cols++) { 
        result_pl[ rows ][ cols ] += matrix1[ rows ][ j ] * matrix2[ j ][ cols ];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why is ISPC file not vectorizing the execution with parallelization by pthreads?

Comment: To maximize the ability for us to help you, you should reduce this to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You might even find out the issue by doing so.

Comment: I have done some changes to the code so that you can easily understand what I want to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is because ISPC defaults to `varying` type.  `int x = 0` is the same as `varying int x = 0`.  This applies to pointer types as well `void *arg` as `void varying * uniform arg` and you can't have varying types in exported functions.  When porting and first getting started with ISPC it's best to be explicit with `uniform` and `varying` keywords.

Comment: That's great to hear!  Also if you run into issues in the future the [ispc-users Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/ispc-users) is probably the best place to seek feedback.